# Efficient pointwise multiplication of blocks in a block matrix

Tags: matlab

Consider two ND block matrices with 2D blocks. For simplicity, consider the 2D matrices `[A B; C D]` and `[E F; G H]`. The submatrices of each matrix can be assumed to have the same size. Is there an efficient way to determine the matrix `[AE BF; CG DH]`, which is similar to the pointwise multiplication of matrices but now at the level of the individual blocks. At the moment I'm using a triple for loop (one over the N dimensions, and two for extracting each subblock) with preallocation and it works, but still it is a real performance killer in my current application. I know it can be easily accomplished by using cell arrays and cellfun, but I prefer a solution without. Is there another, efficient way of performing such an operation?

**Edit**

The algorithm below shows the intended behavior. In the considered application, the block size is even smaller which makes the computations even slower.

```
x = randn(100, 100, 50, 50);
blksize_x = [5, 5];
y = randn(100, 80, 50, 50);
blksize_y = [5, 4];
sx = size(x); sy = size(y);
c = zeros([sx(1), sy(2), prod(sy(3:end))]);

for i=1:prod(sy(3:end))
    for j=1:sx(1) / blksize_x(1) 
        for k=1:sx(2) / blksize_x(2)
            ix1 = (j - 1) * blksize_x(1) + 1:j * blksize_x(1);
            ix2 = (k - 1) * blksize_x(2) + 1:k * blksize_x(2);
            iy1 = (j - 1) * blksize_y(1) + 1:j * blksize_y(1);
            iy2 = (k - 1) * blksize_y(2) + 1:k * blksize_y(2);
            c(ix1, iy2, i) = x(ix1, ix2, i) * y(iy1, iy2, i);
        end
    end
end
c = reshape(c, [sx(1), sy(2:end)]);
```

Comment: `AF` is _matrix_ multiplication, not element-wise multiplication, right?

Comment: Could you describe algebraically the operation that you need done? for example, multiplication of 2 matrices can be written *m(i,j) = a(i,k).b(k,j)* with summation over doubled index *k*. I don't follow the explanation, sorry...

Comment: If it's point-wise multiplication, then elements in each position of one matrix are multiplied by corresponding elements in the corresponding elements in another matrix.  As such, subdividing the matrices into blocks doesn't change the result.  You can simply take each whole matrix and do a point-by-point multiplication with each other.... so I don't get what the problem is here?

Comment: By the way, `cellfun` would make it worse than explicit loops, because anonymous function evaluation is sooooo sloooow. So, good choice on that...